# Find the Id of the point that stay 10 meter apart from each other in python

Tags: python

I calculate the distance matrix by this code:

```
dis_Matrix =  pd.DataFrame(distance_matrix(df.values, df.values), index=df.index, columns=df.index)
```

I have a large distance matrix (10000 by 10000) now, I want to find the id of the points that is 10 meter apart from each other. The points have lat/long and Id

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a Pandas DataFrame -- just having a numpy array will do (assuming your `distance_matrix` gives an N by N matrix where `dist_mat[i, j]` is the distance between the ith and the jth points):

```
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
import numpy as np

# fake some points
data = np.arange(0, 25, 5).reshape(-1, 1)
dist_mat = distance_matrix(data, data)

# `idx0` and `idx1` are the "IDs" of the pairs of points between which
# the distance is smaller than 10:
idx0, idx1 = np.where(dist_mat <= 10)

# You can filter them again to remove duplicates and self-pairs:
mask = idx1 > idx0
idx0 = idx0[mask]
idx1 = idx1[mask]

for i, j in zip(idx0, idx1):
    print('ID0=%d, ID1=%d, distance=%.f' % (i, j, dist_mat[i, j]))
```

Output:

```
ID0=0, ID1=1, distance=5
ID0=0, ID1=2, distance=10
ID0=1, ID1=2, distance=5
ID0=1, ID1=3, distance=10
ID0=2, ID1=3, distance=5
ID0=2, ID1=4, distance=10
ID0=3, ID1=4, distance=5
```

Comment: idx2 = idx2[mask] should be idx0?

Comment: Sorry I messed up the index - fixed now. I also updated the answer to give a reproducible example.